# get redirect URL from an jQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

> **Please vote to close as this is an exact duplicate**

I would like to know the final url of an ajax request once redirected. I'm using jQuery 1.8.0. Any clue?

```js
$("body").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
     console.log(settings.url);                           // got '/a'
     console.log(request.getResponseHeader('Location'));  //got 'null'
});
$('anElt').load('/a');
```

Into /a there is a redirect, using the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /b
```